# Java Simulate realistic gravity

Tags: java, gravity

How would I go about programming a gravity simulator? I am making a kind of 2d space-simulator and what I want is to have a planet (a center of gravity) to pull objects towards it. The object is a spaceship (basically just x and y-coordinates).

Comment: Post some code and show us how far you've gotten and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Princeton's [N-Body](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall14/cos126/assignments/nbody.html) assignment. It describes what you want.

However, in the interest of quick summaries, you can derive the equations from basic trigonometry and Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation:

```
F = GMm/(r^2)
```

where F = force between two objects, G = gravitational constant, M and m are the relevant masses, and r is the distance between them.

A little mathemagic and you get the following results:

```
F_x = F(x_2 - x_1)/r
F_y = F(y_2 - y_1)/r
```

where F_x is the gravitational force in the x direction (same for F_y, but in y direction), x_2 and y_2 is the position of one of your objects, x_1 and y_1 the position of the other, F is as defined above, and r is the distance between them.

Answer (score 2):

Use Newton's laws - the forces two objects feel are attractive (from one objects mass center point to the other's), equal to each other, and in value equal to g*m1*m2/(d*d) (where g is a constant, m1 and m2 are the masses and d is the distance of the center points.

However, if you have a planet, the effect of the spaceship's attraction to the planet is negligible, so one usually does not do the computations for the planet; it's just stationary.

Keep in mind that F=m*a, where F is the force calculated above, m the mass of the spaceship and a is the acceleration of the object. Based on the acceleration you calculate the speed, and based on the speed the position.

Comment: Seeing as there are and x and y-coordinate, the speed would need to be divided so that it can apply to both coordinates. How do I divide the speed?

Comment: @user3808362: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors